# Suggest the native app from your web service

Tags: html, ios, iphone, safari

I saw some time ago in an Apple Keynote that they will implemente (or already implemented) a feature that will allow you to promote your native app from inside your web service.

The example given, if I remember correctly, was with a restaurant table reservation system. When you entered the web service to reserve a table, the browser asked you if you don't want to make the reservation using the native app, from the same service provider, available in App Store. If you choose so, then the phone will download the native app and opened it for you.

Does this feature got implemented ? I don't manage to find it anywhere ?

Comment: You are able to do this by setting a App URL scheme and check on the website if the device knows the App URL scheme. Then if the device does know it you are able to lunch the app, if not you can suggest the user to go to the App Store.

Comment: I had this problem before, and I found out it's not possible to solve it yet: you can't check from JS if the browser will be able to handle an URL scheme. In my case was the tel:// scheme . I know I can put a link to the app, but the solution described by Apple seemed more integrated and streamlined ...

Comment: @nicolea-surdu Yes you can detect this from Javascript, just not the `tel:` scheme perhaps, but we use it for a couple of project and it does work.

Comment: can you please point me in the right direction on how to achieve this ?

Comment: Will try and lookup an example, I know that m.flickr.com does it. It will show you if you have the flickr app installed.

Comment: Well apparently you are not able to detect it directly (although I have seen it done). But Apple provides Smart banner: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for ... Can you post it as an answer ? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple has added a special banner in iOS 6, which you can add to you mobile site. This banner wil be placed at top of your site. The banner will detect if the app is installed or not and allow the user to open the app or download it.

You will find all you need to in [Promoting Apps withApp Banner](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html)